Why the cover of a graph has less number of closed walks
Let $H=(V(H),E(H))$ and $G=(V(G),E(G))$ be two simple graph.
A homomorphism $π: H \to G$ is called a covering map if for every edge $e =
\{u, v\}$ of $G$ and every $u'\in V(H)$ with $π(u')= u$ there is a unique $v'\in π^{−1}(v)$
such that $\{u',v'\}$ is an edge in $E(H)$.
For any $v\in V(G)$, define $W_{\ell}^{(G)}(v)=\#$ walks of length l from v to itself and $W_{\ell}(G)=\min_{v\in V(G)}W_{\ell}^{(G)}(v)$.
I want to prove the following property:
If $\pi:H\to G$ is a cover, then $W_{\ell}(H)\leq W_{\ell}(G)$.
Note that any $H$-cycle about a vertex $v$ gives rise to a unique $G$-cycle about $π(v)$ by the definition of covering map, but I don't know why this fact implies the property for closed walks.

If I understood the definitions correctly, the same property should work for walks and it should be almost exactly the same proof as for cycles.
